# How can I create a progress report event and handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to figure it out, but it's not easy.
In the top of a class I did:
I added the onSearchProgress

```
private EventHandler onSearchComplete;
private EventHandler onSearchProgress;
```

Then in constructor:
I added the onSearchProgress = new EventHandler(OnSearchProgress);

```
public DirectorySearcher()
{
    listBox = new ListBox();
    listBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    Controls.Add(listBox);

    fileListDelegate = new FileListDelegate(AddFiles);
    onSearchComplete = new EventHandler(OnSearchComplete);
    onSearchProgress = new EventHandler(OnSearchProgress);
}
```

Then

```
public event EventHandler SearchComplete;
public event EventHandler SearchProgress;
```

This is the part I want to send as reporting and get it in form1:

```
public int countf = 0;

public void AddFiles(string[] files, int startIndex, int count)
{
    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(files[startIndex + count]);
        countf++;
        textlabel.Text = countf.ToString();
    }
}
```

And

```
private void OnSearchProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchProgress(sender, e);
}
```

Now in Form1 top:

```
private DirectorySearcher directorySearcher;
```

In Form1 constructor:

```
public Form1()
{           
    InitializeComponent();

    directorySearcher.SearchProgress += DirectorySearcher_SearchProgress;
}
```

And

```
private void DirectorySearcher_SearchProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But how do I report from the class and how do I get the report in Form1 in the event? For example in form1 something like:

```
private void DirectorySearcher_SearchProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.textlabel;
}
```

And maybe to add a multiple reporting in the class so I can update more then one labels in Form1. for example:

```
private void DirectorySearcher_SearchProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.textlabel;
    label2.Text = e.textlabel1;
    int counting = e.counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling OnSearchProgress() somewhere in your AddFiles() method. You need to create a new class derived from EventHandler to pass over your additional information (the textLabel in this case) or use a property for that.